# Runtime loading of private assemblies in a subdirectory

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, assembly-resolution

I have been trying to load a private assembly which is located in a subdirectory under the application base directory. I have an assembly named Sparrow.dll which is located under plugins directory (which is under application base dir also). Whenever I call Assembly.Load("Sparrow") I get a System.IO.FileNotFoundException.

I used app.exe.config with  tag and it worked with a strong named version of the same assembly with the line below;

```
Assembly assem = Assembly.Load("Sparrow");
```

However, it does not work when I changed the assembly in to a weak assembly.

The content of the config file is below;

```xml
<configuration>
    <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly name="Sparrow, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx">
            <codeBase version="1.0.1.1" href="plugins/Sparrow.dll" />
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I read many things, but I am not sure whether using  tag for locating weak assemblies is a good practice or not.

Comment: Did you set `PublicKeyToken=null` when you use a weakly-named assembly?

Comment: @JeanHominal: Yes, I did.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`probing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx) element for that purpose:

```xml
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="plugins" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

That element means that the `plugins` subfolder will be searched for assemblies.
Note however, that only directories that are on a descendent path of the application directory can be specified in that way.

The configuration file in your question has a mistake. According to documentation, the XML configuration should look like:

```xml
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <dependentAssembly>
       <assemblyIdentity name="Sparrow"
                          publicKeyToken="null"
                          culture="neutral" />
       <codeBase version="1.0.1.1" href="plugins/Sparrow.dll" />
     </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

However, I think that using the `probing` element would be a better choice in your case.

Comment: That's exactly how I solved the problem. For weak and private  assemblies it is very easy and also works well as far as I see. However, there is lots of information about assemblies which causes the confusion. As far as I understood from the MSDN, using <codebase> for weak assemblies is possible and feasible.

Comment: @Deniz: Did you use a `probing` element with a `privatePath` attribute? Because I do not see that in your question - you used a different element. Also, your current solution is not well-adapted to a system with plugins, as you would need to modify the configuration file for every plugin you would add.

Comment: Not in this question, but I tested it on my computer. You are right, if I use different folders for different plugins then I should add each of them. May be putting every assembly in to a single folder (reserved for plugin assemblies) simplifies the problem. I am open to different solutions of course.

Comment: @Deniz: After re-reading your question, I have seen that there is a mistake in the `<dependentAssembly>` element. Does that fix anything for you?

Comment: You are right. But still not working. By the way, it is a little bit weird for .NET to allow such kind of errors, is't it?

Comment: @Deniz: Please look at [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx) from Scott Hanselmann to debug the issue - I do not have enough information to help you.